# Difference between == and === in Julia arrays and vectors

Tags: arrays, vector, julia

Why is it that `typeof(a) == typeof(v)` is true and `typeof(a) === typeof(v)` is also true, but `a == v` is true and `a === v` is false?

```
julia> a = Array([1,2,3])
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> v = Vector([1,2,3])
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> typeof(a) == typeof(v)
true

julia> typeof(a) === typeof(v)
true

julia> a == v
true

julia> a === v
false
```

Comment: BTW, there is no point in writing `Array([1,2,3])` and `Vector([1,2,3])`. It only takes a vector and converts it to a Vector (which it already is, so it wastes memory and computation). Just write `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: You are wrong. Think a little beat. You should read intently everything I have written. My question only makes sense if I write Array([1,2,3]) and Vector([1,2,3]) and not just [1, 2, 3]. Otherwise, we would get a == v true and a === v also true.

Comment: @PalmerimSoaresdeSá `a = [1,2,3]; v = [1,2,3]; println(a === v)` prints `false`, but `a == v` is true

Comment: Hi, @PalmerimSoaresdeSá. Array and Vector has no effect on [1,2,3], it just creates a copy, so it is redundant, and has no other effect here. @qrsngky's example also shows this. Just try `[1,2,3] === [1,2,3]` and see what happens ;)

Comment: `[1,2,3]` on the left side is one object, `[1,2,3]` on the right side is another object. It is the same as writing `a = [1,2,3]; b = [1,2,3]; a === b`. It should return `false`, as it does, and as explained in the Answer.

Answer (score 4):

`===` determines whether compared objects are identical, in the sense that no program could distinguish them.

So `typeof(a)` and `typeof(v)` are identical (the type is `Vector{Int64}` (alias for `Array{Int64, 1}`) in both cases) so they compare with `===` as `true`.

However `a` and `v`, although they have the same contents do not have the same memory location (you will likely get different values):

```
julia> pointer(a)
Ptr{Int64} @0x000001e6025161b0

julia> pointer(v)
Ptr{Int64} @0x000001e602524f90
```

so they are distinguishable, thus different when compared by `===`.

The `==` is different as it considers just the equality of values. In this case `a` and `v` are arrays of the same shape and storing the same numbers, so comparing them using `==` returns `true`.

In a sense `==` is less strict than `===` when doing a comparison.

Note that e.g. if you used tuples instead of arrays:

```
julia> t1 = (1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)

julia> t2 = (1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)

julia> t1 === t2
true
```

The reason is that tuples are not mutable so even if you create them twice they are in this case considered identical when being compared with `===` (they are not distinguishable).

Finally notice that if you write:

```
julia> a2 = a
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> a2 === a
true
```

The reason is that `a2` and `a` variables point to the same array (i.e. array having the same location in memory).